# Why is the behavior of decltype defined the way it is?

Tags: c++11, decltype

From C++ Draft Standard N3337:

> **7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers**
>
> 4 The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> — if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — otherwise, if e is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> — otherwise, if e is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;

If I understand the above correctly,

```
int a;
decltype(a) b = 10;    // type of b is int

int* ap;
decltype(*ap) c = 10;  // Does not work since type of c is int&
```

Can you explain, or point to some documentation that explains, why `decltype(*ap)` couldn't have been just `int`?

Comment: I assume you know it already :), but for the record you could amend this by using `std::remove_reference` or `std::remove_pointer`.

Comment: @40two, yes I do know of those utilities. I am trying to understand why the language is defined the way it is.

Comment: I knew that you know it since you're a usual suspect in these premises. The main reason I can think of, is for the use of `decltype` in trailing return. Removing `&` from the type would be inconvenient in trailing return I suppose.

Comment: @40two, that could possibly be the(a) reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standardization effort of `decltype` was a herculean effort spanning many years.  There were 7 versions of this paper before the committee finally accepted it.  The versions were:

- [N1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf)  2003-04-28
- [N1527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1527.pdf)  2003-09-21
- [N1607](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1607.pdf)  2004-02-17
- [N1705](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1705.pdf)  2004-09-12
- [N1978](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1978.pdf)  2006-04-24
- [N2115](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2115.pdf)  2006-11-05
- [N2343](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2343.pdf)  2007-07-18

Remarkably, the seeds of the behavior which you question are in the very first revision:  [N1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf), which introduces the need for "two types of typeof:  either to preserve or to drop references in types."

This paper goes on to give a rationale for the reference-preserving variant, including this quote:

> On the other hand, the reference-dropping semantics fails to provide a
>   mechanism for exactly expressing the return types of generic
>   functions, as demonstrated by Strous- trup [Str02]. This implies that
>   a reference-dropping typeof would cause problems for writers of
>   generic libraries.

There is no substitute for reading through these papers.  However one might summarize that `decltype` serves two purposes:

1. To report the declared type of an identifier.
2. To report the type of an expression.

For the second use case, recall that expressions are never reference types, but are instead one of lvalues, xvalues, or prvalues.  By convention, when `decltype` is reporting the type of an lvalue expression, it makes the type an lvalue reference, and when the expression is an xvalue, the reported type becomes an rvalue reference.

In your example, `*ap` is an expression, whereas `a` is an identifier.  So your example makes use of both use cases, as first introduced in [N1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf).

It is also instructive to note that `decltype` was not designed in isolation.  The rest of the C++ language was evolving during this time period (e.g. rvalue references), and the design of `decltype` was iterated to keep pace.

Also note that once the `decltype` proposal was accepted, it continued (and continues to this day) to evolve.  See this list of issues:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_index.html

specifically section 7.1.6.2 (which is the section where the bulk of the `decltype` specification lives).